# Python pandas multiIndex checking index values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am trying to compare two DataFrames for differences, using a common key / index value that is comprised of 3 columns from the frame.

e.g. 
Let's say the columns in both are:
"COL1","COL2","COL3","COL4"

Dataframes are df1 & df2, sourced using the "read_csv" methods.

I've then used the set_index method on both:

```
df1.set_index(["COL1","COL2","COL3"],inplace=True);
df1.sort_index(inplace=True)

df2.set_index(["COL1","COL2","COL3"],inplace=True);
df2.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

I then want to iterate through the df1 dataFrame and check if the df2 one has an index that matches.
I've tried doing that using:

```
for idx, df_select in df1.groupby(level=[0,1,2]):
    boolDf = df2.isin(idx).all();
```

But that returns false (despite the fact that I can see the index exists for both by printing).

What am I doing wrong?

Also, how do I then get the "loc" row from the second Dataframe using the index from the first?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Example data.

testData1.csv contains:
TESTVAL1,TESTVAL2,TESTVAL3,firstCsvVal

testData2.csv contains:
TESTVAL1,TESTVAL2,TESTVAL3,secondCsvVal

code:

```
import pandas as pd

firstFile = "P:\\Documents\\Python\\testData1.csv"
secondFile = "P:\\Documents\\Python\\testData2.csv"

columnNames  =["COL1","COL2","COL3","COL4"]
firstData = pd.read_csv(firstFile,names=columnNames)
secondData = pd.read_csv(secondFile,names=columnNames)

firstData.set_index(["COL1","COL2","COL3"],inplace=True)
firstData.sort_index(inplace=True)

secondData.set_index(["COL1","COL2","COL3"],inplace=True)
secondData.sort_index(inplace=True)

print(firstData)
print(secondData)

for idx, df_select in firstData.groupby(level=[0,1,2]):
    boolDf = secondData.isin(idx).all()
    print(idx,boolDf)
```

Results:

```
                                   COL4
COL1     COL2     COL3
TESTVAL1 TESTVAL2 TESTVAL3  firstCsvVal
                                    COL4
COL1     COL2     COL3
TESTVAL1 TESTVAL2 TESTVAL3  secondCsvVal
('TESTVAL1', 'TESTVAL2', 'TESTVAL3') COL4    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Is your dataframe is of same size ? Can you provide sample datas for df1 and df2 ?

Comment: Thanks @PrinceFrancis, I've updated my question with some sample data and the test code. Is that enough to clarify it? (Thanks again)

Comment: can you provide testData1.csv and testData2.csv ?

Comment: The contents of them are literally the one line for each file that I've included in my post (lines -> "testData1.csv contains:")

Answer (score 0):

If you intention is to find the rows, which are in `df1` but not in `df2` by comparing the columns `"COL1","COL2","COL3"`, you can do as follows

#### left join `df1 and df2`

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=["COL1","COL2","COL3"])
```

#### find the rows which has `NaN`

```
df3[df3.isnull().any(1)]
```

#### to find the rows which are in both `df1 and df2`

```
df3.dropna()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to compare the two dataframe values. i.e. if "COL1", "COL2", and "COL3" match as indexes in both, then compare the data that's held in "COL4"

Comment: I've just realised that the "merge" option may well give me what I need, thanks! (I forgot that the merged columns with the same name are suffixed with "_x" or "_y" for the first and second columns. Therefore, I can merge the two together, iterate the rows and then compare the "COL4_x" vs "COL4_y" :)